# Calculate the center of bbox given gps coordinates

Tags: r, geolocation, tidyverse, r-sf

Given a bbox woth following values:

```
f1 <- base::data.frame("left" = 11.46067, "bottom" = 48.05556 ,"right" = 11.69851 ,"top" = 48.21477)
```

how could i calculate the center point (lat,lon) of this bbox?

Comment: Take the averages in both the x & y directions...? Or am I missing something more complex?

Comment: oh! i think you are right :) i was not sure regarding curverture of the earth and so on

Comment: That could have some impact (not sure tbh) but this seems like a very small area. If you really wanted to, you could create a spatial polygon from this and calculate its centroid, such as with `sf::st_centroid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but the proposed solution does not work for me.
For example given the following bbox (11.360777 48.06162 11.722908 48.24812 ) and the following calculation : median(11.360777, 11.722908) and median(48.06162, 48.24812) accourding to suggestion; it produces a point far away from the center of the bbox.

What did work is to find an intersection of two diagonal lines drawn through the bbox:

```
geosphere::gcIntersect(p1 = c(xmin, ymin),
                       p2=c(xmax, ymax),
                       p3=c(xmax, ymin),
                       p4=c(xmin, ymax))
```

Answer (score 1):

I consider that the median should be used to find the center. I hope this code helps you.

```
library(leaflet)

f1 <- base::data.frame("left" = 11.46067, "bottom" = 48.05556 ,"right" = 11.69851 ,"top" = 48.21477)
point <- c(median(c(f1$left, f1$right)), median(c(f1$bottom, f1$top)))

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addRectangles(lng1 = f1$left, lat1 = f1$bottom, lng2 = f1$right, lat2 = f1$top) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = point[1], lat = point[2])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Out of curiosity, won't the median of two numbers just be their mean?

Comment: You are absolutely right, they are equivalent.

Comment: Somehow is does not work: given the following bbox (11.360777 48.06162  11.722908 48.24812 ) and the following calculation : median(11.360777, 11.722908)  and median(48.06162, 48.24812)  accourding to suggestion; it produces a point far away from the center of the bbox. Do i have a mistake somwhere?

Comment: Hello @Andreas I am testing with my code, that new box and it throws me the point in the center. `f1 <- base::data.frame("left" = 11.360777, "bottom" = 48.06162, "right" = 11.722908, "top" = 48.24812)`

Comment: Hi Rafael, I dont know/dont understand  why it does not work for me. It is probably also a correct approach. But I know for sure that if I calculate the intersection of diagonals it will defnetly provide me with a center point.